# Nginx Conf redirect to a new encoded referer Url in request paramter

Tags: javascript, redirect, nginx

We want to add some rules in nginx.conf file to redirect a coming request to a new url that exists in the request paramaters. for example:

```
  Http://<server1Url>/xyz?referer=http://<server2Url>.
```

in order to do that, we take a parameter which is available as an $arg_ variable and return to the exact match location block. For example:

```
location = /xyz {
return 301 $arg_referer;
```

}

This works successfully but if the referer parameter is encoded it is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: What is “encoded”? Show real examples

Comment: like this for example : Http://<server1Url>/xyz?referer=http%3A%2F%2F%3Cserver2Url%3E